# Nativescript Install Error Post Install script

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, nativescript

I am fine running one of our current projects with Nativescript but when I try to install it on a new project using the following command:

```
sudo ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics the-juice-box --shared
```

I get the following error output:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@10.14.2 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents/lib' 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)

> node-sass@4.10.0 install /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-64 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:753:3)
    at sync (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path:
   '/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@10.14.2 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n    at F (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n    at E (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)\n    at /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n    at /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n    at /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import sys; print "2.7.10
gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 10.14.2
gyp verb command install [ '10.14.2' ]
gyp verb install input version string "10.14.2"
gyp verb install installing version: 10.14.2
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 10.14.2
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1

> nativescript-angular@7.2.3 postinstall /Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/nativescript-angular
> node postinstall.js

fs.js:115
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/hooks'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:753:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jamespuangco/Documents/PrivateWorkspace/ProjectJ/the-juice-box/node_modules/nativescript-angular/postinstall.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 (node_modules/node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nativescript-angular@7.2.3 postinstall: `node postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nativescript-angular@7.2.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jamespuangco/.npm/_logs/2019-04-14T19_19_01_032Z-debug.log
```

I am unsure what to do to fix this issue. I tried reinstalling angular and Nativescript schematics and angular cli. It also says in there permission denied a few times but I am using the sudo command and I am the admin of this laptop so I am need assistance to clarify how to proceed or if I am missing something I need to install. Your assistance is greatly appreciated, I would like to start programming as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try
`npm cache clean` or with `--force` flag like so `npm cache clean --force`

then run `npm cache verify`.

Ensure to have installed the latest version of node and npm.
Finally for EACCES' error i would suggest

`npm config set prefix ~/npm`

npm packages will be stored in your npm folder in your home directory.
then try to re install the packages.